# Subview disappears on UITableViewCell Subclass on scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a subclass of a UITableViewCell that I made in the Interface Builder.

I add a subview to the cell when I load it though which is a 1.0f thick gray separator at the bottom of the cell.

However, whenever I scroll down and the cell with its gray bar leave the view, and then I scroll back up, the gray bar is now gone. If I refresh the page using a pull-to-refresh method that reloads the table, it reappears.

Here is the code that adds the subview:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Make a cell
    ZSWTaskCellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ZSWTaskCellTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIView *bottomSeperator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, cell.frame.size.height, cell.frame.size.width-60, 1)];
    bottomSeperator.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [cell addSubview:bottomSeperator];



    cell.taskLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:18];
    cell.categoryLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Medium" size:14];
    cell.categoryLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

Comment: Why isn't your separator view added to the custom cell in IB? There's no reason do it in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: Given that there's nothing at all dynamic about the subview being added, I agree with rmaddy.  The view should either be added in IB.  Moreover, the label fonts and text colors should also be set up in IB and not in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: I disagree with @nhgrif. Even though I use Storyboards I set up most attributes in code as I uses separated delegate classes that I can re-use in any view controller.

Comment: The cell is dynamic, I have an image that changes if you press a button on the cell. Also the cell heights change based on the amount of content inside the cell.

Comment: @user2554352 How does that affect adding the line in IB? Simply pin it to the bottom of the cell.

Comment: Whether in IB or in `initWithCoder:`, the real point here, @vikingosegundo is that `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is definitely the wrong place for any non-dynamic part of the cell.  You can get it to work there, sure, but it doesn't belong there.

Comment: @nhgrif, I dont disagree about that with you, but using IB doesn't mean you have to use only IB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using a subclass already you should set up it's subviews in the cell class itself.

Depending on other factors you should overwrite `initWithCoder:` and/or `layoutSubviews`. `preparForReuse` might be also mention-worthy.

Note that cells are reused, and you are adding an operator view for each reusing. Depending on the number of rows and scrolling of the user there will be a lot of views.

Add the separator view as a property to your cell subclass and create it just once during initialization of the cell.

Comment: Since the OP is making his cell in IB, he should override initWithCoder:, not initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: which won't be called.

Answer (score 0):

Did you using **heightForRowAtIndexPath** method ? if yes then increase its height resolved problem in my case its driving me crazy. I was trying similar fix